# Update mysql row if value different or create new row not added yet

Tags: mysql

For some reason this is not coming to me, and I do not see this specific question answered where there are two conditions.  I want to update my_table for the following two conditions:

1. If the Primary key vin is the same and the price is different. - or -
2. If there is no vin then just create a new row

Example of before and after two example updates:

[image]

In this exable vin 12345 exist so just the price is update as it's different, in the other example vin 55555 wasn't in the table so it's created.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: _"and I do not see this specific question answered where there are two conditions"_ - that's because there aren't, actually ... apart from that updating the existing row with the same price it already had wouldn't do too much harm (unless there's other restrictions you failed to mention), it won't actually happen, because the DBMS is smart enough to recognize that - see what the documentation has to say about the _affected-rows value_ ...

Comment: I may be going about this the wrong way ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql supports a conditional insert/update - check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO my_table (vin,price) VALUES (12345, 7777)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=7777;
```

Comment: My issue is that I only want to update if the value is different than server value, in your case it is saying just update it with 7777 no matter what value it was in the DB

Comment: @MikeQ and what actual harm do you think that would do? And again - it won't actually happen. The DBMS will recognize that a row already has the values this statement tries to "update" it to, so it will just go, "we're alright here matey, nothing to do, let's move on to the next one" ... so what actual problem do you imagine needs solving here ...?

Comment: Say price = 1234   and on the DB it's 5678,   in your case I would update the DB with 1234 100% of the time.... crap I think I realize now my stupidness ... yeah I am doing the wrong thing here, your answer is correct, I think I need a date component to keep the check from happening all of the time ..  sorry for wasting people's time